# Bounding circle and dual graphs?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Let $X$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with a partition into subsets $X_1,\dots ,X_n$ that are disjoint except on the boundaries. Given this partition we can define the dual graph $G = (V,E)$ where $V= \{ v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and the vertices $v_i,v_j$ share an edge if $X_i$ and $X_j$ are adjacent.

Then given a subset $X_k$, we can define the bounding circle as the smallest circle that contains $X_k$. Is there a notion of a bounding circle for the dual graph $G$? Any definition I try to come up with seems to depend on the planar embedding of the graph.

Comment: By "smallest circle" do you mean "smallest cycle" (graph-theoretically) or do you mean a geometric circle containing the set $X_k$?

Comment: I mean circle containing the set $X_k$. This makes sense in the geometric setting and I want an analogue for the dual graph.